# Sending image file from server after filtering the image file name from DB with image files folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

i created a function -

```
public getImageFile(imageFileName: string) {
 const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, '../images');

 fs.readdir(directoryPath, (e, images) => {
   if (e) { 
     console.log(e) 
   } 

   const filteredImageFilesArray = images.filter(i => imageFileName.includes(i));

   filteredImageFilesArray.forEach((imageFile) => {
       return imageFileName = imageFile;
   });
 });
}
```

the function get a srting, the string is image file name from DB, it compares the file name to a files folder and return the matching file.

i want to send the file from server to client.

here is the server response -

```
  res.status(200).send({
      success: true,
      message: "Successfully retrieved products",
      data: products.map((product) => ({
        id: product.id as string,
        category: {
          value: product.category,
          label: ServerGlobal.getInstance().getCategoryLabel(product.category)!,
        },
        gender: {
          value: product.gender,
          label: ServerGlobal.getInstance().getGenderLabel(product.gender)!,
        },
        title: product.title,
        description: product.description,
        price: product.price,
        imageFileName: ServerGlobal.getInstance().getImageFile(product.imageFileName),
      })),
    });
```

i am getting error on **data** -

Types of property 'imageFileName' are incompatible.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

here is my response interface -

```
type IgetProductsResponse = express.Response<
    IServerResponse & {
        data?: {
            id: string;
            category: { value: ProductCategory, label: string };
            gender: { value: ProductGender, label: string };
            title: string;
            description: string;
            price: number;
            imageFileName: File;
        }[];
    }
>;
```

what can i do for successing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getImageFile` function does not return anything, i.e. its return type is `void`, yet you're trying to use its return value. Another issue with the function is that the function has some operation that runs asynchronously (the `fs.readdir` part, but you're using it as if it was synchronous code when you call `ServerGlobal.getInstance().getImageFile(product.imageFileName)`.

The other question I have is what the `File` type that you have in `imageFileName: File` refers to. Is it in alias for `string`? From the error message that seems to be the case.

So moving on, I will make the following assumptions, you want the `getImageFile()` function to return the file name if it exists, and it should be a `string`. I'm not sure if you want it to be synchronous or async. If you want it to be synchronous you should use `fs.readdirSync` instead. But I will proceed assuming that you want to use the asynchronous API.

If you're sticking to the asynchronous API, I would suggest that you use promises and `async/await` to make the code easier to deal with and avoid callbacks.

You can use the `util.promisify` function to convert the async functions using the callback pattern to using a promise pattern. With that in mind, here are the changes I'd suggest you make to your code:

```js
import { promisify } from "util";
import { readdir as readdirWithCallback } from "fs";

const readdir = promisify(readdirWithCallback);

async public getImageFile(imageFileName: string): Promise<string> {
 const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, '../images');

 const images = await fs.readdir(directoryPath);
 const foundImage = images.find(i => i === imageFileName);
 return foundImage; // this returns null if the imageFileName was not found
}
```

```js
// this should be in a function that has the async keyword
res.status(200).send({
      success: true,
      message: "Successfully retrieved products",
      data: products.map((product) => ({
        id: product.id as string,
        category: {
          value: product.category,
          label: ServerGlobal.getInstance().getCategoryLabel(product.category)!,
        },
        gender: {
          value: product.gender,
          label: ServerGlobal.getInstance().getGenderLabel(product.gender)!,
        },
        title: product.title,
        description: product.description,
        price: product.price,
        // notice the await here, because this is function that returns a promise
        imageFileName: await ServerGlobal.getInstance().getImageFile(product.imageFileName),
      })),
    });
```